# Howto map a unknown complex type within wsimport

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

Currently I try to generate a web service client for a wsdl vis wsimport which works quite fine excepting one complex type:

```
...
<element name="response">
 <complexType>
  <sequence>
   <element name="methodReturn" type="apachesoap:Document"/>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>
</element>
...
```

When I try to generate the client via wsimport I get:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/dev/src/java/prj/src/wsdl/service.wsdl; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 80; undefined simple or complex type 'apachesoap:Document'
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$1.reportError(ParserContext.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.reportError(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.resolve(DelayedRef.java:110)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.DelayedRef.run(DelayedRef.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.getResult(ParserContext.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.getResult(XSOMParser.java:211)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:538)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:269)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2298)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:198)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:141)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:444)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:205)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.Invoker.main(Invoker.java:78)
undefined simple or complex type 'apachesoap:Document'
  line 21 of file:/D:/dev/src/java/prj/src/wsdl/service.wsdl

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.Invoker.main(Invoker.java:78)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.AbortException
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:144)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2298)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:198)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:141)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.buildWsdlModel(WsimportTool.java:444)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:205)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:183)
    ... 5 more
```

When I change the type to
`<element name="methodReturn" type="xsd:anySimpleType"/>`

The client can be generated. So the generation just hangs on the unknown complex type.

**So the question:** Is it possible to provide a custom mapper to wsimport so that the client could be generated withing the "apachesoap:Document" type?

Answer (score 0):

In the WSDL you have to

1. provide namespace for `apachesoap` prefix
2. import or include XSD schema for that namespace with `Document` type defined there. (either in WSDL or into any XSD schema used in WSDL)

then client will be properly generated.

Without it `wsimport` (or any other tools) has no idea what type `apachesoap:Document` actually means.

Comment: The namespace is already provided but there's no xml schema for that entity.
Because of that I want to provide a mapper for that Document by myself. In the end I just need a org.w3c.dom.Document representation.

Comment: Why to do not use standard way and have actual XML Type in response rather than `org.w3c.dom.Document`? I guess you cannot do that since `org.w3c.dom.Document` is not an XML type, but just an `interface`. So, in what form do you think to put such object into XML?

Comment: Since it's a wsdl provided by a thirdparty it need to be a general return type. The returned xml is quite complicated and a xsd cannot be generated or provided. Since it's an interface I want to provide a mapper for that complex type so that I can return an implementation providing this interface.